# Оптимизирует ли SQL логические выражения?

Tags: оптимизация, sql-server, sql

Пусть у нас есть выражение типа

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE condition1 OR condition2
```

Вопросы:

- выполняет ли sql проверку `condition2`
     если `condition1` выполнено для
     некоторой строки, или возвращает
     строку сразу, не проверяя второе
     условие?
- Соответствующее поведение зашито где-то в стандарте или может
     различаться для разных субд?   (В
     частности, интересно поведение для
     mssql2008)

Comment: не уверен, что это описано в стандарте, однако это одна из очевидных оптимизаций, поэтому скорее всего она реализована в любой мало-мальски серьезной субд

Comment: @DreamChild, мало ли, иногда существуют неочевидные причины не реализовывать очевидные оптимизации)

Comment: @Volt ну это уже что-то из области досужих рассуждений. Довольно сложно вообразить действительно вескую причину не сделать эту оптимизацию

Comment: @DreamChild, я могу вообразить - отсутствие определения такого поведения в стандарте было бы очень веской причиной

Comment: Проверка пишется за пару минут на любом языке: http://pastebin.com/Lyt0HN13

    fike@aves:~$ php Temp/php/shorts/query.php 
    Created queries, processing...
    row 0
    row 100
    row 200
    ...
    Presumably short time: 16.126229047775
    Presumably long time: 24.708432912827

Отдельно отмечу, что когда гонял по-другому, первый запрос выполнялся за 4с, второй - за 1с вне зависимости от очередности. Но я сейчас дико хочу спать и мне лень разбираться.

Comment: @Volt, ну тогда у нас веско отсутствуют mysql limit/offset, например

Comment: >отсутствие определения такого поведения в стандарте было бы очень веской причиной

совершенно не веская. Потому что эта оптимизация

а) действительно очень полезна, и способна улучшить производительность

б) никоим образом не противоречит стандарту

Думаю, разработчики СУБД не враги сами себе, чтобы только лишь из-за отсутствия указания на оптимизацию в стандарте, не делать ее, особенно если она способна улучшить производительность (а производительность для субд - это немаловажный критерий)

Comment: @Fike, проверку я разумеется уже написал, но не исключаю что это зависит от конкретной субд или даже от настроек конкретной субд, потому и спросил. Мне хочется услышать того кто знает достаточно точно, как оно работает.

А limit/offset вполне веско отсутствовали в MSSQL. Стандарт как бы говорит нам "эта штука должна быть везде", или не говорит про нее ничего. Вот если не говорят ничего - это дает повод сделать одно и то же совершенно по-разному, руководствуясь своими соображениями о функциональности, оптимизации и мироздании. И оно у людей разное.

Comment: @Volt спасибо конечно за просвещение, но мы тут вас примерно к этой мысли и подводим. Что в отсутствии жестко заданной спеки начинает действовать обычная логика.

Comment: @DreamChild, спасибо, я Вас понял) Ваши рассуждения весьма разумны, но проблема в том, что даже разумные люди думают зачастую очень по-разному. Включая разработчиков разных субд. Вообще не выполнять второе условие - на самом деле не такая очевидная штука, простом мы все к ней привыкли.  
Я был бы рад увидеть в этом топике ответ из разряда "я точно знаю, что так" или ссылку "вот тут авторитетный человек пишет что так"

Comment: Какая речь может идти об оптимизации, если у вас явно неоптимальный запрос будет из-за этого вашего OR (предполагаю там разные поля участвуют в condition1 и condition2)? Типа "я написал цикл `O(n^2)`, какая субд мне его эффективно выполнит и записано ли это в стандарте". притом `n^2` - это еще в лучшем случае, простейшем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конце концов нашел сам:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated

Вкратце: в стандарте написано "делайте как хотите", где-то есть, где-то нет. На существование/несуществование где-то закладываться не стоит.

Comment: тем временем mssql может поступать и так, и этак - например он может сделать index or'ing, если найдет подходящие индексы.